# Powertoys assigning sleep shortcut doesn't work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, powertoys

### Assigning sleep shortcut in Powertoys doesn't work.

I have set sleep button to hibernation in the settings.
Since my keyboard doesn't have sleep button (which is a good thing) I have assigned <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> to trigger the sleep button to send the PC to hibernation.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Steps I've taken to resolve the issue:

- Assigned a different shortcut for the sleep function, but this didn't resolve the problem.
- Reverted the sleep button to its original functionality, yet the issue persisted.

What do I need: I need to assign shortcut to sleep button.

Comment: Sleep process is a BIOS (UEFI) process. I tried remapping Sleep here with Power Toys and it did not work. My keyboard has a physical key to suspend.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in length in the bug-report
[Cannot map key to "Sleep". #5291](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/5291).

The conclusion of the participants was that mapping a key to Sleep
is impossible when the keyboard does not contain a Sleep key.
The opposite is also true - a physical Sleep key cannot be mapped
to any other action.

This is still possible by using the free [AutoHotkey V1](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>Pause</kbd> to the sleep action:

```
#Pause::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 1, "int", 0)
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. For a keyboard shortcut to Sleep, use Microsoft/Sysinternals [PsTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pstools). Make a desktop shortcut with the following and add a keyboard shortcut to it directly, or use a third-party tool such as [AuoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) or [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/?lang=en) to make that shortcut.

   `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Sysinternals\PsTools\psshutdown64.exe" -d -t 0`
2. For a shortcut to Hibernate, just make a desktop shortcut to `shutdown /h`. If you occasionally disable and re-enable Hibernate, you can do it with `powercfg -h on`, run as Administrator.